# Submitting Comments using PHP MySQL debug

Tags: php, html, mysql

Just wondering if anyone can point out where I'm going wrong with the code below. I'm trying to gather the text from the form and UPDATE a field within the database with the text.

I have tested the SQL statement alone and it is updating the column correctly, but seems to be an issue with the PHP syntax as when i click on the submit button, it only insets '1' into the columns.

PHP:

```
$SubmitComments = isset($_POST['SubmitComments']);
$AddComment = isset($_POST['AddComment']);

if ($SubmitComments){

mysql_query ("UPDATE `table` SET `column` = '$AddComment' WHERE `column` = '$.....'") or die(mysql_error());

echo 'Comment added';

}
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
<td>Add Comment</td>
<td align="center"><form name="form1" method="POST" action=""><input name="AddComment" type="text" id="AddComment" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Add comments..." size="45px"><br />

<input type="submit" name="SubmitComments" id="SubmitComments" value="Submit"></form></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/isset  and then go read up about [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) before you get your server pwn3d.

Comment: Why would you be doing an UPDATE if you are trying to create/insert a new comment?  Also, your code is heavily vulnerable to SQL injection.  You should a) consider using mysqli or PDO instead of deprecated mysql_* functions and b) look at using parametrized prepared statements to address the injection vulnerability.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

Right, from the top. `isset` returns a bool, so `$SubmitComments` would only equal true or false, it will never equal the POST variable (Same with `$AddComment`). Consider instead:

```
if(isset($_POST['SubmitComments'])&&isset($_POST['AddComment']))
{
    $SubmitComments = $_POST['SubmitComments'];
    $AddComment = $_POST['AddComment'];
    //Rest of Code
}
```

Second, table and column names do not need single quotes around them. And finally, as addressed in the comments, think about using MySQLi instead as if your script does eventually work, one malformed comment will erase your entire database.

Example:

If their comment is even just `butts';--` It will make the SQL:

`UPDATE table SET column = 'butts';--' WHERE column = '$.....'`

Which is the equivalent of:

`UPDATE table SET column = 'butts';`

Making all of your comments just the word "butts", and that's just a humorously childish attack, compared to stealing usernames/passwords, trashing the database etc